# WiX 3 - Icon is always blank (white)

Tags: installation, wix, icons, wix3.5, wix3.6

i have installed the newest WiX (Installer) for my Visual Studio, and when i want to set the icon, it always ends blank. i'm trying to set the icon of the Entry in "All Windows Software"

in the following Picture you can see how the Icon looks like (Image is from the Internet, not from my example)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/smPKe.png

my code:

```
<Icon Id="Icon" SourceFile="logo_16.ico"/>
<Property Id="ARPPRODUCTICON" Value="Icon" />
```

allready tried different .ico-files. Anyone who knows why and how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please make sure the file is located in the correct directory

```
< Icon Id="ATE_GUI.ico" SourceFile="..\src\ATE_GUI\res\ATE_GUI.ico"/><br>
 < Property Id="ARPPRODUCTICON" Value="ATE_GUI.ico" />
```

this is an example of usage:

```
< Feature Id='Complete' Title='ATE' Description='The complete installation' Display='expand' ConfigurableDirectory='INSTALLFOLDER' Level='1'>
      <ComponentRef Id='ProgramMenuDir' />
< /feature>
```

```
  <Component Id="comp_bin_debug_30" Guid="EB4650EB-75DC-4562-9DC3-8FFDD9B55468">
        <File Id="file_bin_30" Source="..\bin\Debug.x64\ATE.exe" KeyPath="yes" DiskId="1" />
        <Shortcut Id="startmenuATEDebug" Directory="ProgramMenuDir" Name="ATE (Debug.x64)"
      WorkingDirectory='INSTALLDIR' Icon="ATE_GUI.ico" IconIndex="0" Advertise="yes" />     
 </Component>
```

Comment: does it support png image? I am still getting blank icon

Comment: I am getting error - Unresolved reference to symbol 'Icon:Icon.ico' in section in .wxs component section

Comment: I was also getting a blank icon, but was using a `.png` file. When I switched to use a `.ico` file instead, the icon image appeared as expected.